# Phpmyadmin access denied every time ubuntu restarts

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a xampp installation on my ubuntu machine. And I am trying to use `phpmyadmin` to access mysql. But every time I start xampp and try to open phpmyadmin I get an error that says `mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused`. I have read some questions and changing mysql password seems to fix this. But I don't want to change mysql password every time I restart my pc. Is there any way to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to a recent change in MySql for Ubuntu, MySql wont allow root user to login via apache/phpmyadmin/any web interface.

Try login to Mysql in ubuntu terminal and create a new user with root privileges and configuring phpmyadmin to use that user will solve the issue.

Type this in our terminal

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

proceed with your password.

I strongly recommend you to use LAMP stack instead of packaged XAMPP,  (Installing and configuring PHP, Apache2 individually) because XAMPP might not be as handy as it in Windows.